# Key and IV visible in ciphertext object using CryptoJS library

Tags: aes, cryptojs

I am trying to encrypt/decrypt some text using the CryptoJS library.

What I've done so far is, I generate a random key and iv and then I call the AES.encrypt function to encrypt the text.

For example

```
const key = this.generateRandomBytes(32);
const iv = this.generateRandomBytes(16);
let ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("secretMessage", key, { iv: iv });
console.log(ciphertext);
```

What I noticed is that the ciphertext object contains the key and IV, so if I do `ciphertext.iv` I can get the iv value.
This means that by sending the ciphertext object, an attacker could get the iv and key values and decrypt the message.

Is it normal behavior?

Example:

```
key: rGV5ig6haSCITFt3qijtz6upLRwqqTYc 
iv: JYtl1p6QjXEC31l2 
ciphertext: cc7b280b4183a52edf953d67e2780540 

Inside the ciphertext object: 

iv: $super: {init: ƒ, toString: ƒ, concat: ƒ, clamp: ƒ, clone: ƒ, …} init: ƒ () sigBytes: 16 words: (4) [2104546036, 2077723482, 1293309165, -1744950810] __proto__: Object
key: $super: {init: ƒ, toString: ƒ, concat: ƒ, clamp: ƒ, clone: ƒ, …} init: ƒ () sigBytes: 32 words: (12) [811130221, 2012216235, 445216844, 1154159480, 158586942, 1801599139, -1829338835, 1906315595, 2104546036, 2077723482, 1293309165, -1744950810] __proto__: Object
```

Comment: It should contain the only IV and that shouldn't be a problem. Could you also post the key, IV, and ciphertext in hex. Also, note that you should use authentication encryption like AES-GCM, etc.

Comment: key: rGV5ig6haSCITFt3qijtz6upLRwqqTYc
iv: JYtl1p6QjXEC31l2
ciphertext: cc7b280b4183a52edf953d67e2780540

Inside the ciphertext object:
```iv:
$super: {init: ƒ, toString: ƒ, concat: ƒ, clamp: ƒ, clone: ƒ, …}
init: ƒ ()
sigBytes: 16
words: (4) [2104546036, 2077723482, 1293309165, -1744950810]
__proto__: Object

key:
$super: {init: ƒ, toString: ƒ, concat: ƒ, clamp: ƒ, clone: ƒ, …}
init: ƒ ()
sigBytes: 32
words: (12) [811130221, 2012216235, 445216844, 1154159480, 158586942, 1801599139, -1829338835, 1906315595, 2104546036, 2077723482, 1293309165, -1744950810]
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: You can edit your question.

Comment: This means if I do this:

```var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext.ciphertext, ciphertext.key, { iv: ciphertext.iv });
let plaintext = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

I can read the message.

Comment: The message you send the other party must contain only IV and ciphertext and usually, it is prepended as `IV||Ciphertext`. You don't send the object to the other side. The object resides on your site

Comment: How the other side knows then the key?

Comment: With a key agreement protocol like [Diffie-Hellman key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange), or PKI.

Comment: Ok, makes sense, but I still don't get it why the ciphertext object created by this method ```CryptoJS.AES.encrypt```  contains the IV and the key..

Comment: This is completely a library design issue.

Comment: so, the ciphertext object contains also the ciphertext ```ciphertext.ciphertext```. 
this means that the "best-practice" is to send this plus the IV to the other side? Although, the CryptoJS decrypt method accepts the ciphertext object, otherwise it doesn't decrypt anything..